# Xcode build slow for .c and .m files

Tags: xcode, macos, watchman

After updating OSX to High Sierra and updating Xcode to 9.2.0, project build times for bigger projects got out of hand. The build times went from ~10 minutes up to ~120 minutes.

While researching I noticed that Xcode spawns `xcexec` child processes which take most of the cpu usage. `xcexec` spend almost all of the time calling the system `close` call. Each `xcexec` process calls about 2 million close calls per minute.

Upon inspecting the `xcexec` binary, this seems to be a wrapper tool for launching other build actions (e.g. clang).

I have fully reinstalled Xcode with no change. The build system is set to default.

What causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [installation instructions for watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#mac-os-file-descriptor-limits) instructs you to set `kern.maxfiles` like this:

```
 $ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=10485760
 $ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=1048576
```

The default setting for (both of) these values is 131072 on macOS High Sierra. Watchman's suggestion is a 80x change to a performance critical setting of your kernel. Adjusting these values can result in different performance characteristics, especially for file heavy operations like compilation.

Watchman changes the limit so that it is allowed to watch more files at the same time.

Xcode however will start indexing your project and open as many files as allowed (via `kern.maxfiles`). During the compilation phase, Xcode launches `xcexec` which will close any open file descriptors for indexing and only then launch the build step sub-process. That operation should take almost no time. But after changing `kern.maxfiles` it suddenly does.

I benchmarked on an MBP mid 2015, macOS 10.13.3, Xcode 9.2.0.

According to my benchmarking `kern.maxfilesperproc` has no influence on Xcode`s build performance.

The performance of Xcode builds is heavily impacted as soon as `kern.maxfiles` is above 327680.

I recommend setting `kern.maxfiles` to (no value bigger than) 327680 if you need to support watchman with bigger projects.

Note that setting `kern.maxfiles` with `sysctl` is not persistent across reboots. [Adjust the values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/221988) in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist`.

Comment: that section of the watchman documentation is only applicable to old versions of macOS (10.6 and earlier).  You should not apply those configurations on newer systems, as watchman can use fsevents there and that doesn't need higher file descriptor limits

Comment: Thanks for putting the time in to write this! Had the same issue after updaing to Mojave.